# Simple Swift code feature

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I am new to Swift and mobile programming. I am making a simple application. Basically I need to obtain the value from an `@IBOutlet` label.

```
@IBOutlet var currentRoll: UILabel!
```

Below is a segment of my code. In the variable, *totalDice*, I need to add the random number stored in *rolledDice* and the value in *currentRoll*, which is a UILabel. Is there a way that I can obtain the value that prints in the UILabel, *currentRoll*?

```
@IBAction func rollDice (sender: UIButton) {
    var rolledDice = Int(arc4random_uniform(6)+1)
    currentRoll.text = String(rolledDice)
    var totalDice = Int(rolledDice) + __________ (Value of *currentRoll* UILabel)
    totalDisplay.text = String(totalDice)
}
```

Comment: It is better practice to separate your data from your view - Store the current value in an integer variable, add your new value to that and then update the text field

Comment: Use the `text` property of the label and convert it to integer.

Answer (score 0):

@Paulw11 is right that you shouldn't be retrieving this value from the UI, but this is how you could do it.

In your code, you've just updated `currentRoll`, so its text value is going to be the same as `rolledDice` -- but I don't think that's what you meant. Let's move the line in question up one, and try to get the value of `currentRoll` before we update it with the new roll.

```
@IBAction func rollDice(sender: UIButton) {
    // use let instead of var whenever you can
    let rolledDice = Int(arc4random_uniform(6) + 1)

    // initialize totalDice to the newly rolled value
    var totalDice = rolledDice

    // attempt to get a value from currentRoll - String.toInt() returns an Int?
    if let currentDice = currentRoll.text.toInt() {
        totalDice += currentDice
    }

    // update both labels
    currentRoll.text = String(rolledDice)
    totalDisplay.text = String(totalDice)
}
```